# how to rename wp-confing.php file in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

hello everyone I am unable to access my WordPress website because I have renamed wp-confing.php to wp-confing1.php in my AWS ec2 instance. now I am not able to rename wp-confing1.php again. I don't have .pem key pair. now I am not able to rename wp-confing1.php again. Now I am opening the website, so the form for filling in WordPress database details is opening in front of me.

please help me

Comment: You might get a better response at:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use "Ec2 Instance connect". It is on the
*Action* -> *connect* tab in the instance menu.